# How can I reflect over and get the value from this inner class?

Tags: c#, reflection

A user is passing me a string with a class name and another string with a field from that class that I'm supposed to use to extract some information with.  Here are a couple of sample classes; they all inherit from the same base class:

```
public class PersonRow : Row
{
   public static readonly RowFields Fields = new RowFields.Init();

   public class RowFields : RowFieldBase
   {
      public Int32Field Id;
      public StringField FirstName;
      public StringField LastName;
   }

}


public class AutomobileRow : Row
{
  public static readonly RowFields Fields = new RowFields.Init();

  public class RowFields : RowFieldBase
  {
     public Int32Field Id;
     public StringField PaintColor;
     public StringField EngineSize;
  }
}
```

The user will give me something like 'PersonRow' and 'FirstName', from which I need to dive into the `FirstName` field and extract the value of a member in it called `Expression`.

I'll spare the details of what `Int32Field` and `StringField` are doing internally, but suffice it to say both these types have an `Expression` member which is a string I need to use.

I'm trying to use reflection to do this, and have gotten this far:

```
var myClassType = Type.GetType("PersonRow");
var myFields = myClassType.GetField("Fields", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
var fieldListing = myFields.GetValue(null);
```

...at this point `fieldListing` is an object which, underneath the hood, is of type `PersonRow.RowFields`.  However I'm kind of stuck in going past this, in that I'm not sure how to enumerate over that array and extract the `Expression` value from the field I'm interested in?

Comment: An *array* of `RowFields`? Are you sure? You should get an single instance of it. Are you sure you're grabbing the correct type, since you're using `Type.GetType("PersonRow")`?

Comment: Sorry, you're correct, I meant to say 'an object of PersonRow.RowFields', some poor editing on my part which I'll fix now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've slightly modified and stubbed out what appears to be your model, and ended up with this:

```
public class PersonRow
{
    public static readonly RowFields Fields = new RowFields();

    public class RowFields
    {
        public StringField FirstName = new StringField();
        public StringField LastName = new StringField();
    }
}

public class StringField
{
    public StringField()
    {
        expr = Expression.Constant("It worked!");
    }
    public Expression expr { get; set; }
    public string str { get; set; }
}
```

Now, essentially we're looking for the value of `PersonRow.Fields.FirstName.expr`, which can be done with the following code:

```
var personRowType = typeof(PersonRow);

var fieldsField = personRowType.GetField("Fields", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
var fieldsObj = fieldsField.GetValue(null);

var firstNameField = fieldsField.FieldType.GetField("FirstName");
var firstNameObj = firstNameField.GetValue(fieldsObj);

var exprProp = firstNameField.FieldType.GetProperty("expr");
var exprObj = (ConstantExpression)exprProp.GetValue(firstNameObj);
```

Here, `exprObj` will correctly be a `ConstantExpression` with the value `"It worked!"`

Comment: This worked great, thank you.  Didn't know about `FieldType`, appreciate the tip there.